# LAPACKE_cheev only returns upper matrix of eigenvectors

Tags: lapack, eigenvalue, lapacke

I need to compute the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a complex hermitian matrix by using LAPACKE. I found the function LAPACKE_cheev. It computes the eigenvalues correctly. However, it only stores the upper matrix of eigenvectors. I followed the example code found on: [https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/lapacke_cheev_row.c.htm]

My code is basically the same:

```
lapack_complex_float *eigenvectors = (lapack_complex_float*) malloc(num_receivers*num_receivers* sizeof(lapack_complex_float));


//copies upper matrix 'R' into complex matrix 'eigenvalues'
info= LAPACKE_clacpy(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'U', num_receivers,num_receivers,R,num_receivers,eigenvectors,num_receivers);     

int n = num_receivers;
int lda =n;
float w[n];

info = LAPACKE_cheev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'U', n, eigenvectors, lda, w);
```

The matrix eigenvectors simply stores the upper half of the matrix R - this works just fine. 
However, cheev does not store the whole eigenvector matrix - just the upper half. Regarding to the link above this should be the right syntax etc.

Am I missing something?
I would be very grateful for a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a bug in LAPACKE's [`lapacke_cheev_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/d19/a01190_a0bb11fc81c5399c9fee3df67676befc4.html), in version 3.9.0, at line:

```
     /* Transpose output matrices */
     LAPACKE_che_trans( LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, uplo, n, a_t, lda_t, a, lda );
```

Indeed, `LAPACKE_che_trans()` is designed to transpose Hermitian matrices and makes use of their upper or lower half depending on `uplo`. Nevertheless, the output of `cheev('V', ... )` is a matrix made by orthonormal eigenvectors of the input matrix.

The problem also occurs to other eigenvalues-related routines, such as [`lapacke_zheev_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d1a/lapacke__zheev__work_8c_a36e02d4e1ef418164cbca63e0c13e55e.html#a36e02d4e1ef418164cbca63e0c13e55e), [`lapacke_zheevd_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/dcd/lapacke__zheevd__work_8c_source.html)

The routines [`lapacke_zheevr_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/dcd/lapacke__zheevd__work_8c_source.html) and [`lapacke_zheevx_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/dcd/lapacke__zheevd__work_8c_source.html) correctly make use of `LAPACKE_zge_trans()`:

```
if( LAPACKE_lsame( jobz, 'v' ) ) {
    LAPACKE_zge_trans( LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, ncols_z, z_t, ldz_t, z,ldz );
}
```

The example provided at [Intel software development tools](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/index.htm) is also likely plagued by this issue because it also makes use of `LAPACKE_cheev( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V',...)`, which does require transposition.

Looking at the source of LAPACKE in Lapack, version 3.8.0 is not affected by this issue, as it make use of `LAPACKE_cge_trans()`everywhere. Today, the problem only affects LAPACKE 3.9.0, Nov 21, 2019.

Here is a sample code to test it, chaining `LAPACKE_clacpy(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'U',....)` and `LAPACKE_cheev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'U',...)` as you do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <lapacke.h>


int main()
{

 lapack_int i,j, n,  lda, info;
 n=4; 

 lda=n;
 float w[n];

 float complex R [n*n];
 for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
      R[i*n+j]=0.;
    }
    R[i*n+i]=2.;
    if(i>0){
      R[i*n+(i-1)]=-1;
    }
    if(i<n-1){
      R[i*n+(i+1)]=-1;
    }
 }

 float complex eigenvectors [n*n];
 info= LAPACKE_clacpy(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'U', n,n,R,n,eigenvectors,n); 

 if(info !=0){printf("LAPACKE_clacpy error %d\n",info); }   
 info = LAPACKE_cheev(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 'V', 'U', n, eigenvectors, lda, w);
 if(info !=0){printf("LAPACKE_cheev error %d\n",info); }

 for (i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%+6.4f+I*%+6.4f | ",creal(eigenvectors[i*n+j]),cimag(eigenvectors[i*n+j]));
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
 if(creal(eigenvectors[(n-1)*n+0])==0.){
    printf("LAPACKE_cheev : the eigenvectors are wrong due to LAPACKE_che_trans()\n");
    return 1;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

It is compiled by using

```
gcc main11.c -o main11b -L/home/xxxx/softs/lapack-3.9.0/lapack-3.9.0 -llapacke -llapack -lblas -lm -lgfortran -Wall
```

If `-L/home/xxxx/softs/lapack-3.9.0/lapack-3.9.0`, is removed, thus using a version of LAPACK lower than 3.9.0, it outputs:

```
-0.3717+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | 
-0.6015+I*+0.0000 | +0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | 
-0.6015+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.6015+I*+0.0000 | 
-0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.6015+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | +0.3717+I*+0.0000 |
```

If the problem occurs, it prints:

```
-0.3717+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | 
+0.0000+I*+0.0000 | +0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | +0.6015+I*+0.0000 | 
+0.0000+I*+0.0000 | +0.0000+I*+0.0000 | -0.3717+I*+0.0000 | -0.6015+I*+0.0000 | 
+0.0000+I*+0.0000 | +0.0000+I*+0.0000 | +0.0000+I*+0.0000 | +0.3717+I*+0.0000 | 
LAPACKE_cheev : the eigenvectors are wrong due to LAPACKE_che_trans()
```

The problem can be corrected by reproducing the steps performed in previous versions of [`lapacke_cheev_work.c`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/d19/a01190_a0bb11fc81c5399c9fee3df67676befc4.html):

```
 float complex eigenvectors_t [n*n];
 info= LAPACKE_clacpy(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR,'U', n,n,R,n,eigenvectors,n); 
 if(info !=0){printf("LAPACKE_clacpy error %d\n",info); }
 LAPACKE_cge_trans(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n, eigenvectors, n, eigenvectors_t,n);
 info = LAPACKE_cheev(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, 'V', 'U', n, eigenvectors_t, lda, w);
 if(info !=0){printf("LAPACKE_cheev error %d\n",info); }
 //need to transpose back the whole result
 LAPACKE_cge_trans(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, eigenvectors_t, n, eigenvectors,n);
```

I reported [the issue to the github repository of Lapack](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack/issues/379).

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot, I am very grateful! I now use the previous version(3.8.0) and it works perfectly!